# How to get language prefix in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, uri

I am building internal in my custom module that I am porting to Drupal 8:
https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_facets

I need to get a current language prefix so I can prepend it to the link. I Drupal 7 it was as simple as:

```
global $language;
$prefix = $language->prefix;
$mylink = $prefix . '/example/something';
```

How can do this in Drupal 8?

EDIT: My issue specifically is that I have a language prefix set to `NONE` for the default language at `Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Regional and language >> Languages >> Detection and selection`. (admin/config/regional/language/detection/url)

For the default language, I want the code to return the real prefix, i. e. `NONE`, not `en` (the code for the default language, English).

Comment: @Kevin Not a dupe-- the linked question is about Twig files; this question is about getting the language for the URL path.

Answer (score 8):

In Drupal 8, you use the [languageManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Language%21LanguageManager.php/class/LanguageManager/8.4.x) class to get the language code:

```
$languagecode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

EDIT: If you want to return `NONE` if the current language is the default language, you probably need to make a helper function:

```
$languagecode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$default_languagecode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
if ($languagecode == $default_languagecode) {
  return "NONE";
}
else {
  return $languagecode;
}
```

helper function to ge it from settings

```
function getLanguagePrefix() {
    if($prefixes = \Drupal::config('language.negotiation')->get('url.prefixes')) {
      $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
      return "/". $prefixes[$language];
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this issue is that if I have language prefix se to non for default language in
Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Regional and language  >> Languages >>  Detection and selection

admin/config/regional/language/detection/url

Comment: @DarkoKantic What's the issue?  If you set the prefix to none, you don't get a language code?

Comment: sorry, problem in commentin, yes, this is my intended comment
Thanks, this works if there is prefix set for all languages. My issue is that  I have language prefix set to 'non',  for a default language, in
Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Regional and language  >> Languages >>  Detection and selection.

admin/config/regional/language/detection/url

In my case the  above code will return me 'en' for my default language, English. Is there a way to return real prefix, i. e. non for this case?

Comment: @DarkoKantic I updated my answer.  I don't know of any easy way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I also create helper function to get prefix from settings

Comment: Since language id and prefix are different things and you want to pick the prefix, here is the code:


        `$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
        $prefixes = \Drupal::config('language.negotiation')->get('url.prefixes');
        $language_prefix = $prefixes[$language->getId()];`